# How to use phonegap-1.3.0.js in xcode 5.1.1 for camera functions

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

By using phonegap and XCode I have developed a iOS application for iPad. By using phonegap 1.3.0.js with XCode 4.3 I have completed the image capturing camera and image selection from ipad album.

The main Problem is I have updated the X Code version to X Code 5.1.1 and installed phone gap 2.9.1 version in my MAC MINI. But when I am testing the application in ipad2 the image capturing and image selection is not working. Being new to phone-gap with X Code I am unable to identify the issue where it occurring. Right now I am using the cordova .js which is inbuilt in phone gap 2.9.1.

The JavaScript functions are calling but the syntax

`navigator.camera. get Picture();` from that line.

The code I have used is as below

```
var imageLength = 0;

function take Picture() {
    navigator.camera.get Picture()
};
```

can you please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
var pictureSource; // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// device APIs are available
//

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) {
    alert("fire");
    // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
    console.log(imageURI);
    // Get image handle
    //
    var cameraImage = document.getElementById('image');
    // Unhide image elements
    //
    cameraImage.style.display = 'block';
    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    //
    cameraImage.src = imageURI;
}
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    alert("fire");
    // Uncomment to view the image file URI
    console.log(imageURI);
    // Get image handle
    //
    var galleryImage = document.getElementById('image');
    // Unhide image elements
    //
    galleryImage.style.display = 'block';
    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    //
    galleryImage.src = imageURI;
}
// A button will call this function
//

function capturePhoto() {
    // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 30,
        targetWidth: 600,
        targetHeight: 600,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });
}
// A button will call this function
//

function getPhoto(source) {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 30,
        targetWidth: 600,
        targetHeight: 600,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source
    });
}
// Called if something bad happens.
//

function onFail(message) {
    //alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

You can download my sample code here: https://github.com/datomnurdin/com.revivalx.cordova.camera

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply.
The main problem is when I am calling the javascript function it is calling but stoping at navigator.camera.getPicture(). After that syntax I am not getting any response. For your information I am using PhoneGap 2.9.1 , codova 3.5.0 XCode 5.1.1. 
I have placed the latest cordova.js file in www folder with perfect path given in index.html file. Can you suggest me how to use the cordova.js for XCode 5.1.1 with Phonegap 2.9.1

Comment: Hi Mohammad Can you tell how to use this functionality according to cordova 3.5.0 version